# Angular Material mat-autocomplete not working in production mode

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

i'm trying to implement a mat-autocomplete field, just like the documentation says.
It is working on ng serve as expected. But when I do ng build --prod, and deploy it to firebase, it does not work.
Console shows no errors. The field is shown on screen, but it does not filter my data, or have any events at all.

ng version shows:

[ng version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snkrq.png)

--I had to post an image because i could not make it work to post the html here, it kept saying it was not indented although i did use ctrl + K.

[template field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhdFs.jpg)

this is the related functions

[typescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiFeU.png)

Again, locally it works just fine. Filters, triggers, selects, and even process data, where i send it to my backend api.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if it was the solution, but after updating most of my angular dependencies, and running npm install, this code worked.
I had versions 10.0.10 for angular modules, and my material was at 10.1.3
After update they were 10.2.5, and material 10.2.7

Also, i tried using formControlName with the  related to the mat-autocomplete but that also seemed to break the component, so i guess [formControl] is the directive that works (although there's nothing mentioned in the documentation).